# Is Amplify Web Hosting making use of CloudFront CDN by default?

Tags: aws-amplify

In other words, does amplify take care automatically to allocate your website static resources in edge locations? It does so many things for you that, at some point, it becomes hard to distinguish what it does and what not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, AWS Amplify uses CloudFront by default.**

This is what they say on the website:

---

Q: How is hosting a modern web app different from a traditional web app?

Hosting a modern web app does not require web servers and can use content delivery networks to store static content (HTML, CSS and JavaScript files). **AWS Amplify leverages the Amazon CloudFront Global Edge Network to distribute your web app globally** .

---

You can learn more on https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/faqs/?nc1=h_ls .